# Nodejs: In ejs renderFile function, linked CSS File is not working in callback HTML

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am trying to get the HTML from EJS using ejs.renderFile function. Purpose is so that I can made an image of that html and attach to an email.
The problem I am facing is that the CSS file I linked in EJS is not working i.e (styling not applied).
My main goal is to link the 'bootstrap.min.css' file for styling and use classes of Bootstrap.
please see the code.

```
   function sendBusinessQuotaEmail() {
 const template = `${process.cwd() + "/emailTemplates/businessQuotaEmailTemplate/businessQuotaEmailTemplate.ejs"}`;
const options = [`${process.cwd() + "/emailTemplates/businessQuotaEmailTemplate/businessQuotaEmailTemplate.css"}`];
const templateData = [{abc: 'test'}];
console.log('here sendBusinessQuotaEmail');
ejs.renderFile(template, templateData, (err, html) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ejs render file error on line # 7209', err);
        return;
    }
    console.log('html', html);
    nodeHtmlToImage({output: `${process.cwd() + "/tempFiles/download/abc.jpg"}`,html: `${html}`}).then(() => {
        console.log('The image was created successfully!');
    });
});
```

}
[image]
[image]